# How to read individual bits from an array?

Tags: c++, binary

Lets say i have an array dynamically allocated.

```
int* array=new int[10]
```

That is 10*4=40 bytes or 10*32=320 bits.  I want to read the 2nd bit of the 30th byte or 242nd bit.  What is the easiest way to do so?  I know I can access the 30th byte using array[30] but accessing individual bits is more tricky.

Comment: Possible `std::bitset` is suitable for your needs

Comment: If you wish to have bitwise access always ensure you are using the `uint8_t` type for the data. Otherwise machine data sizes and endianess may cause you problems.

Comment: @edA-qa more-ora-y uint16_t, etc. also work.  For most uses, so does unsigned char, unsigned int, etc.  Endianess isn't a problem, and carefully written (using sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT, rather than 8, 16, etc.) isn't either.  Supposing the program requires that degree of portability.

Comment: The concern about endianess is that if you have an int array presumably you might be assigning integers to it and then accessing it by byte. If you only ever use bytes you are correct that it won't matter, but at least use unsigned.

Comment: Actually, to access 30th byte you use array[29] not array[30] :)

Answer (score 6):

```
bool bitset(void const * data, int bitindex) {
  int byte = bitindex / 8;
  int bit = bitindex % 8;
  unsigned char const * u = (unsigned char const *) data;
  return (u[byte] & (1<<bit)) != 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not based on the array described by Jake.

Comment: @Benoit: sure is, if he pass the array to this function it'll work fine. The only case where the above will fail is funny machines with bytes not being 8 bits wide.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `!= 0` part. Simply masking and implicit conversion would be enough.

Comment: Yes, but it's not nearly as readable, since it involves an implicit conversion.

Comment: @edA: uint8_t is C99, not C++  - and being explicit when answering is a Good Thing, the `!= 0` makes it very clear what is tested for.

Comment: <cstdint> in C++ defines uint8_t.

Comment: @edA: That's TR1 - which isn't a standard. It'll be in C++0x though

Comment: @Eric: You can use `CHARBITS` defined in `<climits>` instead of 8 to be more portable

Comment: @Armen: You mean `CHAR_BIT` - but yes, that'd fix it for funny CPUs.

Comment: @Erik: yes, that was what I meant )

Answer (score 1):

this is working !

```
#define GET_BIT(p, n) ((((unsigned char *)p)[n/8] >> (n%8)) & 0x01)

int main()
{
    int myArray[2] = { 0xaaaaaaaa, 0x00ff00ff };
    for( int i =0 ; i < 2*32 ; i++ )
        printf("%d", GET_BIT(myArray, i));
    return 0;
}
```

ouput :

> 0101010101010101010101010101010111111111000000001111111100000000

Be carefull of the endiannes !

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're doing bitwise operations, it's usually
preferable to make the elements an unsigned integral type
(although in this case, it really doesn't make that much
difference).  As for accessing the bits: to access bit i in an
array of n int's:

```
static int const bitsPerWord = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;
assert( i >= 0 && i < n * bitsPerWord );
int wordIndex = i / bitsPerWord;
int bitIndex = i % bitsPerWord;
```

then to read:

```
return (array[wordIndex] & (1 << bitIndex)) != 0;
```

to set:

```
array[wordIndex] |= 1 << bitIndex;
```

and to reset:

```
array[wordIndex] &= ~(1 << bitIndex);
```

Or you can use bitset, if `n` is constant, or `vector<bool>` or
`boost::dynamic_bitset` if it's not, and let someone else do the
work.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED based on comment below - array contains int of 32 bits, not 8 bits uchar.

```
int pos = 241; // I start at index 0
bool bit242 = (array[pos/32] >> (pos%32)) & 1;
```

Comment: His array is int - not char/unsigned char - you can't use `/8` and `%8`

Comment: Or that CHAR_BIT is 8:-).  But the division is on pos; an assert on the value should precede the code anyway: negatives aren't the only problem:

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
!((array[30] & 2) == 0)
```

**array[30]** is the integer.

**& 2** is an and operation which masks the second bit (2 = 00000010)

**== 0** will check if the mask result is 0

**!** will negate that result, because we're checking if it's 1 not zero....

Answer (score 0):

You need bit operations here...

```
if(array[5] & 0x1)
{
//the first bit in array[5] is 1
}
else
{
//the first bit is 0
}

if(array[5] & 0x8)
{
//the 4th bit in array[5] is 1
}
else
{
//the 4th bit is 0
}
```

0x8 is 00001000 in binary. Doing the anding masks all other bits and allows you to see if the bit is 1 or 0.

int is typically 32 bits, so you would need to do some arithmetic to get a certain bit number in the entire array.